# assign class to outer wrapper of a customized component in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How can we assign a class to the outmost wrapper of a component in React?

For example, I was trying to add class "table" to this "FilterableProductTable" so that the outmost wrapper, "" in this case, can have a class assigned to it?

What I did is to add prop "className={"table"}", but it does not seem to work. When inspected, the outmost div still doesn't have a class.

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable className={'table'} products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

[the outmost div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N51g.png)

[the outer wrapper div still doesn't have a class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eufl.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely possible.  You must remember that `FilterableProductTable` is a Component and doesn't represent a DOM node element, like `div`, so you are actually just passing a property called `className` to your Component. It is then up to your component to use the passed in property.

For e.g.

```
class FilterableProductTable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.className}>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable className='table' products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

If you notice above I am actually accessing the passed in property called `className` via `this.props` in the `FilterableProductTable`.  So any properties you set on a Component when rendering it will be passed into the Component, and then it is up to the Component's own rendering logic how it wants to use those properties.

You could have called the property `foo` or whatever too, for e.g.:

```
class FilterableProductTable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.foo}>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable foo='table' products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Look at the React docs, all the following are HTML Elements natively supported by React:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#html-elements

If you set the `className` prop on those items then the class would be attached to them directly. :)

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. I think I phrased the question in the wrong  way, I actually want to ask how to add class to a specific instance of the component, but I think your solution would also work even in that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On the outermost div of the `FilterableProductTable` component you need to include the `className` prop:

```
<div className={this.props.className}>
    {...children}
</div>
```